# Why can't I see my messageField created from class file?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, adobe-animate

```
class Game
{
    constructor(root, lib)
    {
        this.root = root;
        this.stage = this.root.stage;
        this.canvas = this.root.canvas;
        this.messageField = this.root.messageField;
        this.lib = lib;
        this.init();
        this.keys ={}; 
    }
    
   init(e){
        this.player = this.root.player_mc;
        
        const game = this;
        
        document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
  
    console.log(`Key "${e.key}" pressed [event: keydown]`);
            this.keys[e.key] = true;
  
});
        document.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
  
    console.log(`Key "${e.key}" pressed [event: keydown]`);
            this.keys[e.key] = false;
  
});
    
   
    //Message display field
       
    this.canvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
    this.stage = new createjs.Stage(this.canvas);
    this.messageField = new createjs.Text("Loading", "bold 68px Arial", "#OOOOOO");
    this.messageField.maxWidth = 1000;
    this.messageField.textAlign = "center";
    this.messageField.textBaseline = "middle";
    this.messageField.x = canvas.width / 2;
    this.messageField.y = canvas.height / 2;
    this.stage.addChild(this.root.messageField);
    this.stage.update(e);   //update the stage to show text
    console.log(this.messageField.text);
    
    }
   
}
```

I have this code on my class file game.js - the keys are being logged, the messageField can be logged in the console, but there is no text in the project when it is run.  No errors are being thrown by this code.  Any pointers greatly appreciated :)
thank you
sub

I have been working on how to create working Javascript to run from a game.js file to control an adobe animate cc HTML5 Canvas.

I have been asking various questions here and working out how to make it go
https://community.adobe.com/t5/animate-discussions/changing-code-to-get-it-to-work-from-a-class/td-p/13454073#M360897
and here for the current query
https://community.adobe.com/t5/animate-discussions/how-to-get-a-messagefield-working-from-a-class-file/td-p/13455867

I did notice that the text is set to white and thought if I changed it to black I would see the text (I was very happy with myself for a moment)- but you still can't see the text in the final project

Comment: I am not exactly familiar with **JS** side of **Flash**, but purely out of **OOP** logic: There is a pre-existing **TextField** object (let's call it **R**) that resides at **root.messageField**, and a class member **this.messageField** (let's call it **L**). First, you do **L** = **R**, so **L** holds a reference to **R**, but you never use it. Then, you instantiate a totally new **TextField** with some text, and put it into **L**, but then again you do **addChild** (directly specified **R**). This way, newly created **TextField** never actually makes it to the display list.